# resetting a copy of an array in an angular function after .splice()

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

What I am trying to accomplish is making a dropdown menu in angular that removes the current page from the list. When the next view is loaded I want the menu to reset and remove the now current view.

The array of objects that make up the dropdown menu

```
var menuItems = [
    {menuItem: 'home', url: '/'},
    {menuItem: 'depth', url: '/depth'},
    {menuItem: 'bolt circle', url: '/bolt_circle'}
];
```

The angular function that sort() the array and .slice() out the current page from the array.

```
       $scope.sort = function(){
           $scope.items = menuItems;
           for(i=$scope.items.length-1; i>=0; i--){
               var obj = $scope.items[i];

           if($location.path() === obj.url){
               $scope.items.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
```

I am rather new to angular and javascript, so I am not making the connection as to why menuItems is seemingly being .splice() as well as $scope.items, Each time I go to a page it gets deleted from the menu until I have no links left. I would have thought making a copy of the array each time the sort() function is run would give me a fresh copy of the array.I hope I explained that well enough.

Comment: what about ng-if and ng-hide?

Comment: yes, this was something else that was suggested to me after posting the question. Nothing wrong with doing it that way I suppose, I just had the idea of doing it the other way first. Would there be any pro's or con's to one way over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$scope.items = menuItems;
```

you are **not** making a copy of the `menuItems` array, instead you are creating a new property `items` in the `$scope` Object that will have the **same array reference** as `menuItems`. This means that `$scope.items` and `menuItems` are the same.

In order to create a copy of the `menuItems` array you should do this:

```
$scope.items = menuItems.slice(0);
```

Comment: I was convinced this was an angular problem. Now that I understand the root of the problem, this page explains it perfectly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice Your answer was spot on.